# How to pass array data type as argument in store procedure. I would liketo pass multiple values as input parameter

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am writing the procedure as below. Passing the values as Array and binding it while running the sql .

While calling the procedure (call procedure proc_test1(array_construct('a','b')))
getting unsupported data type binding error.

```
    create  or replace procedure proc_test1(PRAM Array)
          returns varchar not null
          language JavaScript
          as
          $$
         
          
         
          
          var step0='select value from table(flatten(input =>parse_json(:1))';
          var statement0=snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: step0,binds: [PARAM]} );
          var res1 = statement0.execute();
          while (res1.next())  {
          
          var column_val1 = res1.getColumnValue(1);
           
          try {
          snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "begin transaction;"} );
          
          
          var step1=`insert into table1(column1,column2) select column1,column2 from table2 where 
     column3=:1;`
          var statement1=snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: step1,binds: [column_val1]} );
           statement1.execute();
           result="Succeeded";
              
       snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "commit;"} );
           
           }catch (err)  {
               snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "rollback;"} );
              result =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
              result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
              result += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt; 
              }
          return result;
          
          
       }
     
      $$
```